# How to upload an image to Rails article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, trix

I'm rebuilding a blog in Rails, and I'm using Trix for my text-editor. I have everything regarding Trix set up and in place. I can drag an image and drop it into the Trix text-editor and when I click Create Article, I get no errors. But when I go to view the article, there is no image. This seems like a very easy fix.

show.html.erb

```
<h1>Showing Blog Posts</h1>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text.html_safe %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

article_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @articles = Article.all 
    end

    def show
       @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
          redirect_to @article
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update 
       @article = Article.find(params[:id])

       if @article.update(article_params)
           redirect_to @article
       else
           render 'edit'
       end
    end

    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
        end
end
```

articles.coffee
(code for uploading image to Trix editor)

```
$ ->
  document.addEventListener 'trix-attachment-add', (event) ->
    attachment = event.attachment
    if attachment.file
      return sendFile(attachment)
    return

  document.addEventListener 'trix-attachment-remove', (event) ->
    attachment = event.attachment
    deleteFile attachment

  sendFile = (attachment) ->
    file = attachment.file
    form = new FormData
    form.append 'Content-Type', file.type
    form.append 'image[image]', file
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.open 'POST', '/images', true

    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) ->
      progress = undefined
      progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100
      attachment.setUploadProgress progress

    xhr.onload = ->
      response = JSON.parse(@responseText)
      attachment.setAttributes
        url: response.url
        image_id: response.image_id
        href: response.url

    xhr.send form

  deleteFile = (n) ->
    $.ajax
      type: 'DELETE'
      url: '/images/' + n.attachment.attributes.values.image_id
      cache: false
      contentType: false
      processData: false

  return
```

Comment: Trix sends the image as multipart to your server. Though once your server has received the image it has to process it and save it (locally or more likely on a remote hosting service such as Amazon AWS S3). You need to add an attachment gem such as Paperclip, Carriewave or Shrine.. it will deal with the file and you can even do some process on this file (resize the image etc..)(will need image magick locally as well). By the way, using Rails for a blog is maybe overkill, unless this is on purpose.

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: I use Paperclip and it's pretty straightforward. Shrine is the most advanced (too much engineered for a blog I guess). They all have specificities (temp file management etc..). Make sure your form sends files as multipart. (Easy to do in HTML but not sure how Trix sends to the server)